# How to display each skill bar next to each text line?

Tags: html, css

I need the webpage to display information on a single line, like this:

> Progress in this course (100%) "Skill bar here displaying 100 %"

However, my code displays the webpage like this:

> Progress in this course (100%)
>
> "Skill bar here displaying 100 %"

**My code:**

```css
.Bar {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 200px;
}

.Bar span {
  height: 5px;
  float: left;
  background: #2187e7;
}

.Hundred {
  width: 100%;
}

.TwoHundred {
  width: 50%;
}

.ThreeHundred {
  width: 77%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container1">
  <p>Progress in this course (100%)</p><span class="Bar"><span class="Hundred"></span></span>
</div>
<div class="Container2">
  <p>Progress in the specialization capstone (50%)</p><span class="Bar"><span class="TwoHundred"></span></span>
</div>
<div class="Container3">
  <p>Progress in life goals (70%)</p><span class="Bar"><span class="ThreeHundred"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `[class^=class="Container] p { display: inline-block; }` and remove `float: left;` from `span`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually with your code you just need to change the `.Bar` display to `inline block`, and wrap the `p` on it and that's it.

```css
.Bar{
    background: lightgrey;
    height: 5px;
    display: inline-block; /* changed from block */
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;
}

.Bar span {
    height: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: #2187e7;
}
.Hundred{
    width:100%;
}
.TwoHundred{
    width: 50%;
}
.ThreeHundred{
    width: 77%;
}
```

```html
        <div class="Container1">
            <p>Progress in this course (100%)<span class="Bar"><span class="Hundred"></span></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Container2">
            <p>Progress in the specialization capstone (50%)<span class="Bar"><span class="TwoHundred"></span></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Container3">
            <p>Progress in life goals (70%)<span class="Bar"><span class="ThreeHundred"></span></span></p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css

```
.Container1 {
  display : flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Additionally you may need to provide some margin to the Bar, for spacing, depending on your choice.

```
.Bar {
    margin-left: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give an additional class names "container" OR as you want to all divs

```
<div class="Container1 container">....</div>
<div class="Container2 container">....</div>
<div class="Container3 container">....</div>
```

and below CSS as::

```
.container {
  display : flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```